# Is Chase Paymentech Orbital Gateway Supported on App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, payment-gateway

Is it possible to integrate chase paymentech orbital gateway with Java Google App Engine based application. As per my understanding it needs to set environmental variable for paymentech sdk and it would not be  possible to use it on app engine. If any body have exp on using it on app engine then please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the GAE part, but can point you [a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35377381/2094015) which may help.

As for the environment variable part, depending on what language you are using then setting it before interacting with their SDK should do the trick.